# Creating MySQL views with id to work with Django

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

**How do I either add an auto-incremented id column to the view and/or tell Django not to look for the 'id' field?**

I have a mysql view that I wish to define as a self-managed Django model

```
managed = False
```

I don't have an id column because I am doing multiple joins and the resulting view has more rows than any of the joined tables.

I get a `1054` error When I try to access the model

```
myview.objects.all()
```

```sh
OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'myview.id' in 'field list'")
```

*Answer:* The best I have found so far is something like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myview AS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY <field>) as id, ...
```

Comment: Is there any column that will be unique for the view? Depending on how you use this model you may be able to get away with not having an id column. Can you show how you will be using the model, will you be using it in the admin, performing joins with it or accessing individual rows?

Comment: I ended up using the four columns that are unique together with *ROW_NUMBER() over (colums) as id*

Comment: Cool, I've previously just marked a random field as the primary key when I've done something similar, Django doesn't actually check that each row has a unique pk value. This works so long as you don't try to look up a row by pk obviously